# android not showing result from php

Tags: php, android-studio

simple code to show connection in android

php code address : http://kardgar.gigfa.com/toosab/connect.php?i=1

I also add uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

and MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String res = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    new getcount("http://kardgar.gigfa.com/toosab/connect.php").execute();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,res ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

and getcount.java

```
public class getcount extends AsyncTask{

private String Link="";

public getcount(String link ){

    Link=link;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

    try{

        String data = "";

        URL mylink=new URL(Link);
        URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();

        connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();  

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        String line=null;

        while((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){

            sb.append(line);
        }

        MainActivity.res = sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception ignored){

    }

    return "";
}
```

}

and when I run this code I get something else
[image]

Comment: it shows html file in another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems gigfa.com comes with the limitation that only regular web browsers can access it (which is done by returning a page first the contains JavaScript that the browser has to run first, and you see this page in your app now!). This is done using [this anti-bot module](https://kyprizel.github.io/testcookie-nginx-module/).

Your direct HTTP request is not a web browser, it's considered a bot.

The solution is to check in your hoster's control panel if there is an option to disable this bot protection for your endpoint (maybe that's possible only in the paid plans) or move your site to another web hosting provider without this limitation.